# Wrap array and subarray's in an unordered list

Tags: php, arrays, api, function

I am using an API call that returns an array. It's an array not a sting. I want to wrap the array in an unordered list. I need two separate lists.

1) I want to wrap everything (including sub arrays) in an unordered list.

```
<ul>
  <li>[name]</li>
  <li>[name]</li>
  <li>[name]</li>
</ul>
```

2) I just want to wrap [name] in an unordered list.

```
<ul>
  <li>[1347037874]</li>
    <ul>
      <li>[level_id]</li>
      <li>[name]</li>
      <li>[canceled]</li>
      <li>[cancelDate]</li>
      <li>and all the rest</li>
    </ul>
  <li>[1347037874]</li>
    <ul>
      <li>[level_id]</li>
      <li>[name]</li>
      <li>[canceled]</li>
      <li>[cancelDate]</li>
      <li>and all the rest</li>
    </ul>
</ul>
```

I assign the API call like this:

```
$member_id = $logged_in_WP_user_id;
$member_levels = member_levels($member_id);
```

For explanation only (this line is not in my function...when I output $member_levels like this: `htmlspecialchars(print_r(get_member($member_id),true))` I get the following:

```
Array
( 
    [1347037874] => stdClass Object
        (
            [Level_ID] => 1347037874
            [Name] => HFM-Cardiac Resistance Training Program
            [Cancelled] => 
            [CancelDate] => 
            [Pending] => 
            [UnConfirmed] => 
            [Expired] => 
            [ExpiryDate] => 
            [Active] => 1
            [Status] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Active
                )

            [Timestamp] => 1349804951
            [TxnID] => WL-2-1347037874
        )

    [1347037875] => stdClass Object
        (
            [Level_ID] => 1347037875
            [Name] => HFM-Official Heart Health Guide
            [Cancelled] => 
            [CancelDate] => 
            [Pending] => 
            [UnConfirmed] => 
            [Expired] => 
            [ExpiryDate] => 
            [Active] => 1
            [Status] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Active
                )

            [Timestamp] => 1349804951
            [TxnID] => WL-2-1347037875
        )
)
```

I have tried several ways to wrap the array in an array, it get close but still can make it work right.

Tks!

p.s. here is what I am now using to make the first list but how do I get the other key values to display as in unordered list under the key value =>Name.

```
$member_levels = ember_levels($member_id);

  $output  = '';    
  $output .= '<ul>';                            
  foreach($member_levels as $level) {
    $output .= '<li>' . $level_array[]=$level->Name . '</li>';
  }
  $output .= '</ul>';

  print_r($output);
```

Comment: You might want to give an example output for a list element.

Comment: PHP doesn't have unordered lists. It has associative arrays and indexed arrays (which are actually just a special case of associative arrays where the keys are successive integers).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach($member_levels as $level)
{

  $level_array[]=$level->Level_ID;
  $name_array[]=$level->Name;
}
```

Comment: That works for my first list. I did; however, change the key value to =>Name but how do you get all the other key value to display as a an unordered list under =>Name?

I added the code to the bottom of my post above as to how I used your suggestion to output my list.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to wrap something in another level of array, do:

```
$wrapped_thing = array($something);
```

If this doesn't do what you want, then you haven't described it well.